# boost regex and ifstream

Tags: c++, boost-regex

Is there a way to use the regex class of boost to search in a file without completely reading it into memory?

I currently read a file per line and this makes the parsing quite complicate compared to searching via regex. I do it per line because the files can be huge and I don't want to waste to much RAM.

The regex expression I would like to use is, and it works fine if I use it for Example in Notepad++

```
Block *\{([^\}]*?)MY_TOOL_Library([^\}]*?)\}
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457595/can-you-use-boost-regex-to-parse-a-stream

Answer (score 2):

I don't think boost regex implements this.  They require a bi-directional
iterator.

Formally, "regular expressions" (in the mathematical sense) allow one
pass parsing, and can be made to work with a forward iterator.  But
boost, like most other regular expressions, implements capture (an
extension to the formal definition), and I think that this precludes a
true one pass algorithm (or makes it extremely difficult).

Comment: This I already know
But I asked if there is a workaround available
Looks likes there is no "easy" way around..