# How to match a stream of bytes with PCRE

Tags: c++, c, regex, pcre

I'm trying using [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) to match regular expressions. In some cases, however, I want to do "streaming" matching. Because of issues like look-behind assertions, I cannot simply discard the matched part and match the rest. Is there any function or algorithm to correctly match a stream of bytes without storing them all?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any function or algorithm to correctly match a stream of bytes without storing them all?

In general, no, for reasons you have mentioned. But in some cases, yes, you could.

I don't believe you can do that with PCRE.

You can use [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) with [partial match](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/partial_matches.html).

See also [Can you use Boost.Regex to parse a stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457595/can-you-use-boost-regex-to-parse-a-stream)

Comment: PCRE has partial matches as well. But I'm not sure how to use partial matches to do stream matching. It seems to have many pitfalls as well. In the URL you give me, there is an example that `abc|b` will always produce only a partial match against `b`. But if `b` is at the end of stream, it should be full match. That is different than loading the whole thing into buffer and do full match.